# How to set property durable for a queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

I try to migrate my Apache Camel application from component [RabbitMQ](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/rabbitmq-component.html) to component [Spring RabbitMQ](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/spring-rabbitmq-component.html). Unfortunately some defaults are changed. One is the `durable` property for queues (see [Durability](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#durability)), which is now `false` by default.

**Code**

```java
from(springRabbitmq("my_exchange")
        .routingKey("my_routing_key")
        .queues("q_my_queue")
        .autoDeclare(true))
```

**Versions**

- Apache Camel 4.0.0
- Spring Boot 3.1.3

**Logs**

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'q_my_queue' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

**Research**

- I read [`SpringRabbitMQEndpointConsumerBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-endpointdsl/4.0.0/org/apache/camel/builder/endpoint/dsl/SpringRabbitMQEndpointBuilderFactory.SpringRabbitMQEndpointConsumerBuilder.html), but there is no method for `durable`.
- I read [`AdvancedSpringRabbitMQEndpointConsumerBuilder`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-endpointdsl/4.0.0/org/apache/camel/builder/endpoint/dsl/SpringRabbitMQEndpointBuilderFactory.AdvancedSpringRabbitMQEndpointConsumerBuilder.html), but there is no method for `durable`.
- I read [AUTO DECLARE EXCHANGES, QUEUES AND BINDINGS](https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/spring-rabbitmq-component.html#_auto_declare_exchanges_queues_and_bindings)

  > The elements can be configured using the multi-valued `args` option.
  >
  > For example to specify the queue as durable and exclusive, you can configure the endpoint uri with
  > `arg.queue.durable=true&arg.queue.exclusive=true`.

  but I want to use [endpoint DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/Endpoint-dsl.html).
- I read [`args`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-endpointdsl/4.0.0/org/apache/camel/builder/endpoint/dsl/SpringRabbitMQEndpointBuilderFactory.AdvancedSpringRabbitMQEndpointConsumerBuilder.html#args(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object))

  > Specify arguments for configuring the different RabbitMQ concepts, a different prefix is required for each element: arg.consumer. arg.exchange. arg.queue. arg.binding. arg.dlq.exchange. arg.dlq.queue. arg.dlq.binding. For example to declare a queue with message ttl argument: args=arg.queue.x-message-ttl=60000. The option is a: `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>` type. The option is multivalued, and you can use the args(String, Object) method to add a value (call the method multiple times to set more values). Group: advanced

  and tried

  ```java
  from(springRabbitmq("my_exchange")
          .routingKey("my_routing_key")
          .queues("q_my_queue")
          .autoDeclare(true)
          .advanced()
          .args("arg.queue.durable", true))
  ```

  and

  ```java
  from(springRabbitmq("my_exchange")
          .routingKey("my_routing_key")
          .queues("q_my_queue")
          .autoDeclare(true)
          .advanced()
          .args("arg.queue.durable", "true"))
  ```

  but I got the same error.

**Question**

How can I set the property `durable` for a queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
from(springRabbitmq("my_exchange")
    ...
    .args("queue.durable", "true"))
```

Comment: The docs leave much to be desired. In SpringRabbitMQEndpointBuilderFactory I've found the implementation of .args method that seems to explain why it should work:

Comment: `default AdvancedSpringRabbitMQEndpointConsumerBuilder args(Map values) {             doSetMultiValueProperties("args", "arg.", values);             return this;         }`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reference for the key.  At the top of class SpringRabbitMQEndpoint you can find constants such as QUEUE_ARG_PREFIX (mapping to "queue.") etc...